# Grid Layout does not display correctly

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build simple calculator gui with display and 9 buttons

```
public void init()
    {
        setSize(60,80);
        inf = new InfoButton(this);
        zero = new CalcButton(this,"0");
        one = new CalcButton(this,"1");
        add = new CalcButton(this,"+");
        sub = new CalcButton(this,"-");
        div = new CalcButton(this,"/");
        mlt = new CalcButton(this,"*");
        modu = new CalcButton(this,"%");
        blank = new JButton("");
        wys = new Wyswietlacz(); // its JTextPane
        wys.setSize(60,20);
        przyciski = new JPanel();
        przyciski.setSize(60,60);
        przyciski.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        przyciski.add(zero);
        przyciski.add(one);
        przyciski.add(add);
        przyciski.add(sub);
        przyciski.add(mlt);
        przyciski.add(div);
        przyciski.add(modu);
        przyciski.add(inf);
        przyciski.add(blank);
        calosc = new JPanel();
        calosc.setLayout(new BoxLayout(calosc,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        calosc.add(wys);
        calosc.add(przyciski);
        calosc.setSize(60,80);
        add(calosc);



    }
```

and in main i make frame with size `(60,80)` but when i make it visible all i can see is display and one row of buttons. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Really bad idea to be using setSize, key the layout managers deal with it and use JFrame#pack to set the size of the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call setPreferredSize(..) instead of setSize() on wys and przyciski. Then use JFrame's pack() instead of specifying a size for it.